# Finding the maximum in given outputs

Tags: c++

I have written a code to find the largest palindrome formed by multiplication of two 3-digit numbers. However instead of just getting the desired answer i.e. the largest palindrome, I am getting the list of all possible palindromes. How do I program it to find the largest.
Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int revfunc(int x) {
    int rev = 0, num, d;
    num = x;
    while(num != 0) {
        d = num % 10;
        rev = (rev * 10) + d;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    long int maxi = 0;
    if(x == rev && maxi < x) {
        maxi=x;
        cout<<maxi<<endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    long int ans;
    for(int i = 100; i <= 999; i++) {
        for(int j = 100; j <= 999; j++) {
            ans = i * j;
            revfunc(ans);
        }
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `C`? This is `C++`. Also note that there is a huge difference between `C` and `C++`. You don't need to tag this `C++`, `C++11`, `C++14`. Just choose one of them.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: Also thanks martijnn2008. I learned today what good presentation is from you!

Answer (score 1):

In your program you don't actually select the maximum palindrome, you just dump them all. Here is minimal correction for code to work:

```
bool revfunc(int x){
    int rev = 0, num, d;
    num = x;
    while (num != 0){
        d = num % 10;
        rev = (rev * 10) + d;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    long int maxi = 0;
    return x == rev&&maxi < x;
}

int main()
{
    int max_palindrome = 0;
    long int ans;
    for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++){
        for (int j = 100; j <= 999; j++){
            ans = i*j;
            if (ans > max_palindrome && revfunc(ans))
            {
                max_palindrome = ans;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << max_palindrome;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @CodeFuller. If possible could you just walk me through it? What significance did changing int to bool make?

Comment: revfunc() now determines whether the number is palindrome, that's why it returns bool. Main cycle then checks whether current i*j is a palindrome and updates final result if it's bigger than previous known palindrome value.